# ConnectionStrings.Config Referencing Env Var or Key Vault Entry?

Tags: azure, key, web-config, sitecore, azure-keyvault

Have a Asp.NET forms web application, hosted in Azure, with a connectionstrings.config file that needs to reference a value from a Azure Key Vault.

This entry is used by another integrated system, Sitecore, that uses Azure Cognitive Search for its internal search.  Therefore, the value needs to be changed within the config file.

As an example, this is an entry in the config that needs a value from the Key Vault.

```
<add name="cloud.search" connectionString="serviceUrl=https://someurl.com;apiVersion=2017-11-11;apiKey=**key vault value**"/>
```

Is there a way to reference a value from a keyvault here?  If necessary, I could reference a value from the web application's configuration settings on Azure - which in turn can pull the value from the key vault.

Answer (score 1):

We can refer `Environment Variable` as well as `Key Vault` in our Configuration file.

> Is there a way to reference a value from a keyvault here?

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax)

To refer `Key Vault`, Syntax to access `keyVault` secret from our `WebApp` using `ManagedIdentity` has to be,

```cs
ConnectionString=@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=value from KeyVault Secret)
```

- The value has to be the full Connection String in Key vault secret.

[image]

- Get the Secret Identifier.

[image]

***Example :***

```cs
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConn" connectionString="@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://harshukv5apr.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyDBContext/**********)" providerName="****" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

***Azure App Connection String***

[image]

- Enable the `System asigned Identity`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the answer, so thank you.  Before posting this question, I did extensively search for the answer; however, search terms like "config" and "key" and "vault" are too common and the results are not easy to wade through.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is working correctly.  If access the connection string programmatically in C# and log it, it still shows @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=someUri" .  Is this correct?  Is there a way to get check the keyvault value when used in conjunction with the connection string?

Comment: Have you given the required permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have.  First, I went through the MS doc which has tighter permissions than you actually have.  I added the permissions you suggest and it's the same problem.  Is there a way to see/debug this?

Comment: Also,in the above section ***Azure App Connection String ***, you are making a configuration setting with a value of "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=value from KeyVault Secret)"  Why?  Where is this referenced/used?

Comment: `access the connection string programmatically in C# and log it, it still shows @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=someUri"`.Can you please share your code.

Comment: SearchDebug = $"{searchDebug} cloud.search = {ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cloud.search"].ConnectionString}<br>";